# Pushing a task with firebase-queue not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin, firebase-queue

I am trying to use the [queuing module](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-queue/blob/HEAD/docs/guide.md) base on top of Firebase. I use the following code to push tasks

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS),
  databaseURL: 'gs://xxx.appspot.com/'
});


var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("queue");

ref.child('tasks').push({"name": "this is a push from the client"}).then(function(){ process.exit();});
```

But nothing is happening. The task is not pushed and the pushing task does not exit or throw any error

Comment: Firebase Queue was essentially obsoleted by Cloud Functions.  In fact, this is the very first thing you'll see in the [readme](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-queue/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration looks wrong:

```
databaseURL: 'gs://xxx.appspot.com/'
```

URLs for the Realtime Database start with `https://` and end with either `firebaseio.com` or `firebasedatabase.app`. So I recommend double checking the configuaration data in the Firebase console and grabbing the value from the correct key.